# Python Canopy: Is it possible to do word wrap in the editor?

Tags: python, canopy

I am using Canopy for editing and running files. But I am finding it difficult to take a look into more than 80 lines of code in it.

Is it possible to enable word wrapping in Canopy Editor?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the editor does not yet support soft (display-only) wrapping.

The User's Guide includes an example of a macro to do hard (insert newlines) wrapping, but that is usually not what one wants:
http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/macro_howto.html#writing-macros-from-scratch

FWIW, Python standards specify a maximum line length of 79 characters:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Comment: ok. thx. I have set it to 80 char, but at times for readability I used to expand the console that makes it difficult to read the code along side the console output,